# Adafruit QT PY ESP32-S2 stuck in CircuitPython mode

Tags: microcontroller, arduino-esp32, adafruit-circuitpython

I have an adafruit qt py esp32-s2 that i accidently put in ciruitpython mode which means that i cant upload any arduino code to it. Idk why this happends all i know is that i need to be able to upload arduino code to it, otherwise i need to buy a new one.

I tried to put the board in download mode by holding the BOOT button and pressing RST and then releasing the BOOT button. Then i flashed my code to the board, which works. Then i pressed the RST button and the board shows a purple light, a red light and then a green light before the board opens a new drive on the computer that is called QTPYS2BOOT or something like that.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Once the virtual drive shows up, the board is ready for an upload. Either drag and drop a new UF2 onto it (micropythin, circuitpython, flash_nuke.uf2, or whatever). From my googling, that's also the point where the Arduino IDE is ready to upload a new sketch. So... maybe try uploading an Arduino 'blink' sketch then.  Here's a link about flash-nuke if you need it...  https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberrypipico/comments/q41gx9/finding_the_nuke_option/?rdt=39816

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out that the Partition Scheme was not set to Default 4MB with spiffs (1.2MB APP/1.5MB SPIFFS)

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4CB.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Adafruit esp32s3 reverse tft came with a program installed. I could use circuitpython but uploads from the arduino ide failed most of the time. This was solved by using esptool.py to erase the flash memory. At the bottom of the page below are the instructions I followed.
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-esp32-s3-tft-feather/factory-reset